# PageAdapter with activity

Tags: android, view, android-3.0-honeycomb, fragment

i'm using Xoom and honeycomb to develop a app using a viewpager/pageAdapter to make a horizontal slide with many screens(using a compatibility package and http://code.google.com/p/viewpagerexample/)....but i have some difficult to put activities and start fragments in some screens.
Is that anyway to this better???? here my code above

main activity call PageAdapter

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);  
    ActionBar action = getActionBar();       

    //action.setTitle();
    action.show();
    cxt = this;
    awesomeAdapter = new AwesomePagerAdapter();
    awesomePager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.awesomepager);
    awesomePager.setAdapter(awesomeAdapter);

}
```

//instantiateItem in PageAdapter

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
    LayoutInflater inflate = (LayoutInflater) cxt.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = new View(cxt);
    if(position == 0) {
        view =inflate.inflate(R.layout.home,null);  
        ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view,0);   
    }
    else if (position == 1) {
        view =inflate.inflate(R.layout.frentes,null);
        ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view,0);   
    }
    else if(position == 2) {
        view =inflate.inflate(R.layout.equipamentos,null);
        ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view,0);   
    }

    return view;
}
```

If Position == 1 i want to call the activity not inflate a view because in the frentes(activity) i call a fragment....

i hope that idea is clear...because my english is not so good

Thanks in advance
Igor